# Optional where clause in prepared query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, shortest-path

this is a question about code optimization, because my code works good but I think there is an easier way to do what I did, I explain, I have an admin interface where admin can search courses, but the search can be specific, I mean you can search by Author or/and by Category or/and by School, and if you do NOT choose any of these options it returns all the courses  so here is my code and it works I used the logic because I send an array called `$param` that contains 3 values. Look at the `$query` value and it just change on `Where` clause

```
Author School Category
   0     0       0
   0     0       1
   0     1       0 
   0     1       1 
   1     0       0 
   1     0       1
   1     1       0
   1     1       1
```

and my code works with this same way

```
if(($param[0]==0)&&($param[1]==0)&&($param[2]==0))
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId  ";

else if( ($param[0]==0)  &&  ($param[1]==0) && (intval($param[2])>=1)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId WHERE categoriaId = ?;";
}
else if( ($param[0]==0)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && ($param[2]==0)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId WHERE escuelasId = ?; ";
}
else if( ($param[0]==0)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && (intval($param[2])>=1)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId  WHERE escuelasId = ? AND categoriaId = ?; ";
}
else if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ($param[1]==0) && ($param[2]==0)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId  WHERE autorId = ?; ";
}
else if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ($param[1]==0) && (intval($param[2])>=1)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId   WHERE autorId = ? AND categoriaId = ?;";
}
else if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && ($param[2]==0)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId  WHERE autorId = ? AND escuelasId = ?; ";
}
else if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && (intval($param[0])>=1)){
    $query = "SELECT idCurso, tema, indice, descripcion, fecha, idioma, imagenes.ubicacion as imgLocation, enlaces, nivel, keywords, autorId, escuelasId, categoriaId, subcategoriaId FROM plataforma.cursos INNER JOIN imagenes ON imagenes.idImagen = cursos.imagenId  WHERE autorId = ? escuelasId = ? AND categoriaId = ?;";
}
//"asi quedo ".$query;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {



    /* bind result variables */
    if(($param[0]==0)&&($param[1]==0)&&($param[2]==0)) {

    }
    if( ($param[0]==0)  &&  ($param[1]==0) && (intval($param[2])>=1)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$param[2]);
        //echo $param[2];
    }
    if( ($param[0]==0)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && ($param[2]==0)){
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$param[1]);
    }
    if( ($param[0]==0)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && (intval($param[2])>=1)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ii",$param[1],$param[2]);
    }
    if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ($param[1]==0) && ($param[2]==0)){
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$param[0]);
    }
    if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ($param[1]==0) && (intval($param[2])>=1)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ii",$param[0],$param[2]);
    }
    if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && ($param[2]==0)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ii",$param[0],$param[1]);
    }
    if( ( intval($param[0])>=1)  &&  ( intval($param[1])>=1) && (intval($param[0])>=1)){
        $stmt->bind_param("iii",$param[0],$param[1],$param[2]);
    }
/* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();
```

I set `$param[x]>=1` because if the value is 0 means that the field was not selected but if it is selected it must have a value greater or equal than 1
And like I said before, This code works, but I know It can be less, but I don't Know the way

Comment: If you have working code and are just looking for ways to improve it, your question belongs on [codereview.se]. This site is for questions related to actual problems you're facing with your code, not peer review.

Comment: Sticking to parameterized queries doesn't mean completely forgoing dynamically constructed queries; it just means avoiding constructing them directly with parameter values. (Pseudocode: _if parameter present, append "[AND|OR|WHATEVER] corresponding_field = ?", and bind value._)

Comment: Note if you would use PDO you wouldn't have to bind parameters and your life would be easier! Also as mentioned above, you should start with a base query and just append to it based on variables.

Comment: Also, are those parameters really strings? You are binding them with `s` as if they are.

Comment: Have you tried [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)?

Comment: @KenWhite I always search here for my errors, and I have seen other questions that are for improve, so i did this question, i'll mark as answered  then

Comment: That was back before CodeReview existed. If you search here, you'll also find posts that are not on topic any longer after [su] was created, or [unix.se], or [ubuntu.se], or [programmers.se]. Existence of a previous question has no relevance; what matters now are the *current site guidelines*, and under those your question is more suitable for [codereview.se] instead.